# Transform fortran code to matlab

Tags: matlab, fortran

How do i tranform this code below to matlab? I got confused on goto statement.

```
do 57 i=1,10
        statement 1
        if(k .eq. nx) then
          statement 2
          go to 58
        end if
 57   continue
      statement 3
 58   continue
```

Comment: MATLAB doesn't have `goto`, but with a small moficitation and using `break` you should be able to achieve a similar effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GOTO command is not considered as a good procedural programming.
Use the following program instead:

```
i=1;
t=true;
while (i<=10)&&t
  statement1;
  t=k~=nx;
  i=i+1;
end

if t
  statement2;
else
  statement3;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This Fortran Snippet has a very bad code-smell to it.

But here are a few things:

`true` here seems to be a variable. The correct value for true in Fortran is `.TRUE.` (or `.true.`). Assuming that that variable is always `.TRUE.`, then the code can be rewritten very easily:

```
statement 1
statement 2
```

And that's it. Your code would immediately jump out of the loop and over `statement 3`, so each of the statements would only be executed once.

But assuming that `true` is some variable or expression that has to be re-evaluated in each iteration of the loop, this is a better way:

```
do i = 1, 10
    statement 1
    if (true) exit
end do
if (true) then
    statement 2
else
    statement 3
end if
```

Now this still assumes that `true` is a static expression, that is that it won't change it's value between calls.

Comment: thank you for the solution.. actually `true` is logical expression that return bool value..

Comment: Look at his earlier revision, he had a valid logical statement in the `if`.  His editing it to `true` is likely just an artifact of his lack of Fortran knowledge not realizing that isn't how we say `.true.`.